# How to start daemon on android by adb

Tags: android, android-ndk, adb

Can you help me please, my head is swollen...

I am trying to run daemon on android emu/device by command:

```
adb -s <device_name> shell su -c /dir/daemon <port_number>
```

but nothink happens, and no errors!

If I do:

```
adb -s <device> shell
```

and then form shell cmdline:

```
su -c /dir/daemon <port_number>
```

than its work fine. I try use shell-script and run:

```
adb -s <device_name> shell sh su -c /dir/script.sh <port_number>
```

and I even try to generate script from Qt code with port number and use:

```
adb -s <device_name> shell sh su -c /dir/script.sh
```

but its not helped... problem that if I enter to adb shell previous to run daemon - its work. Another problem is on different device/emu/iso_image different command format could not work. For example:

```
adb -s <device_name> shell su -c /dir/daemon <port_number> // work at emu, but not at iso
```

and vice:

```
adb -s <device_name> shell su -c "/dir/daemon <port_number>" // work at iso
```

etc.

Everybody can answer what's the matter?

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
adb shell su -c "/dir > /dev/null 2> /dev/null < /dev/null &"
```

or

```
shell su -c /data/local/tmp/start_daemon.sh

#!/system/bin/sh
/data/local/tmp/nohup 
/data/local/tmp/daemon <portn_number> &
```